# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props') onPress

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

React native beginner here, Im trying to pass from login to HomeTeacher/HomeParent, according to the status in the database (firestore). When I'm printing the status, he is good ("Teacher"/"Parent"), but it doesnt go the HomeParent/HomeTeacher
When I press on the button I get the "Error getting document: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation')]" error...

Here is my code :

```
  import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground,Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import background from "../Images/background.jpg";
import Logo from "../Images/Independo.png";
import firebase, { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';
require('firebase/auth')
require('firebase/firestore')

const {width : WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window')

const screenHeight=Dimensions.get('window').height
const screenWidth=Dimensions.get('window').width

class LoginAdult extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      email:'',
      password:'',
     // status:''
    }
  }




  LoginPress= async()=>{
    const {email,password,}=this.state;
    if(this.state.email && this.state.password)
    {firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
    {
      if (user != null) 
      {
        var docRef=firebase.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user.uid);
        docRef.get().then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              const {status} = doc.data();
              if(status=="Teacher")
              {
                console.log("status = ",status)
                this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeTeacher")
              }
              else if(status=="Parent")
              {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeParent")
              }
          } else {
              console.log("No such document!");
          }
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
    }
  }))

    
    .catch((error)=>{
      switch(error.code)
      {
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
          alert("Please, enter a valid mail")
          break;
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
          alert('A user with this email doesnt exist, please sign Up')
          break;
      }
    
      
    })

  }
  else{
    alert("Please enter email and password!")
  }
  }
  
        


  render(){
  return (
    <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.imagebackground}>
      <View style={{header:25,backgroundColor:"",alignItems:'center',marginTop:40}}>
      <Image source={Logo} style={styles.logo}/>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1,borderWidth:0,borderColor:'transparent',margin:40,marginTop:0,marginBottom:220}}>

        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"#F9f3fc",alignItems:'center',paddingTop:35,borderRadius:15,borderStyle:'dotted solid double'}}>



            <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:30,paddingBottom:30}}>LOGIN</Text>

            <TextInput 
              style={styles.input} 
              placeholderTextColor={'black'} 
              placeholder={'Email'}
              onChangeText={inputEmail=>this.setState({email:inputEmail})}/>

            <TextInput 
              style={styles.input} 
              placeholderTextColor={'black'} 
              placeholder={'Password'} 
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onChangeText={inputPassword=>this.setState({password:inputPassword})}/>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin} onPress={()=>this.LoginPress()}>
              <Text style={{fontWeight:'600'}}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>


          <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("SignUp")}>
                            <Text>Dont have an account?  </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row',margin:4}}
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("ForgotPasswordAdult")}>
                            <Text style={{textDecorationLine:'underline' ,fontSize:16 ,fontWeight:'bold',}}>
                              Forgot Password?  
                              </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>





        </View>

      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
}

export default LoginAdult;
```

Comment: Are you using React Navigation 4 or 5? please share your entire js code on this file, not just the LoginPress function because I think the problem is not on this function

Comment: I have edited the entire js code

Comment: Im using the version 4 ('4.4.4')

Comment: It works only when I put   **this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeParent")** before **if(this.state.email && this.state.password)** ,

Comment: The error message you are getting hints as to a `_this2.props.navigation` being undefined, however in the code snippet you shared there is no such variable, only `this.props.navigation`, is this correct? 
Maybe somewhere else in your code there could be this variable wrongly stated, as a typo perhaps, could you check that and share the mentioned block of code where this is located?